# Correct spelling and/or hyphenation for electronic commerce

Tags: orthography, hyphenation, internet

What is the correct spelling and/or hyphenation for the abbreviation of electronic commerce?

I have seen the following variations.

- eCommerce
- E-Commerce
- ECommerce
- E-commerce

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [this Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=E-Commerce%2CeCommerce%2CECommerce%2CE-commerce%2CEcommerce&year_start=1998&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CE%20-%20Commerce%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CeCommerce%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CECommerce%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CE%20-%20commerce%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CEcommerce%3B%2Cc0), both  **E-Commerce** and **E-commerce** are valid and interchangeable:
[image]

Likewise, when *not* beginning a sentence (or in a headline, etc.), the term **e-commerce** is not capitalized:

> **e-commerce** |ˈēˌkämərs|:
>
> (noun) commercial transactions conducted electronically on the Internet.

[See what happens](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=E-Commerce%2CeCommerce%2CECommerce%2CE-commerce%2CEcommerce%2Ce-commerce&year_start=1998&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CE%20-%20Commerce%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CeCommerce%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CECommerce%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CE%20-%20commerce%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CEcommerce%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ce%20-%20commerce%3B%2Cc0)  when **e-commerce** is added to the Ngram.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-commerce), **eCommerce** is a viable, though less often used alternative. The Ngram supports that assertion. The only variation which is *completely* incorrect is **ECommerce.**

Definition from: *New Oxford American Dictionary*

***Conclusion:***

- ***E-Commerce*** is almost always hyphenated. The only non-hyphenated alternative is ***eCommerce.***
- Furthermore, ***e-commerce*** is not capitalized unless one begins a sentence with it, or uses it in a headline/title.
- When capitalized, both ***E-commerce*** and ***E-Commerce*** are correct, though I prefer the latter.

Comment: I don't know why, but in business, I've always used 'eCommerce' unless at the start of a sentence and then 'Ecommerce'. Interesting to know that each variation is accepted.